# Getting Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1 error

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to export a CSV from my client's FluidSurvey's account and import it into a database I've created. I've never actually worked with a CSV before, so excuse my ignorance.

I've looked into this error and none of the solutions seem to be working for me, I'm at a loss, I've been trying to import this file for hours now.

Settings are as follows:

[image: 1]
[image: 1]

There is already a table with columns for this data to be inserted into.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You've showed exported csv file in Excel or Calc. It is impossible to understand how you columns are enclosed. Probably there is some sign other than ' or " Please show exported csv in notepad. This will clear the structure of csv.

Comment: See, you have tabs instead of "

Comment: Change the structure in csv according your import settings or adjust import settings to a csv file structure. Looks like you have to change tabulation to comma

Answer (score 0):

I found that Fluidsurveys CSV files had the header two bytes incorrect.
They are only 7F7E. Changing them to the expected Unicode FFFE works as expected - they can be read into Excel with no garbage characters at the start.